# How to create a user with Pusher on React Native?

Tags: react-native, pusher, pusher-js

I try to follow official document https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-app-react-native-gifted-chat and it works.

But when I want to set a create user function , I can't find the code from React Native.

I just find it with Node.js https://docs.pusher.com/chatkit/reference/server-node#creating-a-user and with Javascript https://docs.pusher.com/chatkit/quick_start/javascript#create-a-user

If i use Javascript document, it will show error `https://docs.pusher.com/chatkit/quick_start/javascript#create-a-user`

```
import Chatkit from "@pusher/chatkit";

    const chatkit = new Chatkit.default({
      instanceLocator: CHATKIT_TOKEN_PROVIDER_ENDPOINT,
      key: CHATKIT_SECRET_KEY
    })
```

There is no `default` can be used obviously.

Is any way to do it on the mobile application or I must have a backend to do it ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can create users in one of three ways:

- Using your [Chatkit dashboard's](https://dash.pusher.com) console
- From your server code using one of the [server SDKs](https://docs.pusher.com/chatkit/resources#server-sdk)
- Using the [HTTP API](https://docs.pusher.com/chatkit/reference/api#create-a-user) directly

As you'll notice from that list, you can't create a user from the client.